# Prove that, if limit exists, then there are $\delta>0$ and $M>0$ such that $|f(x)| \le M$

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}f(x) = L$. Prove that there are $\delta>0$ and $M>0$ such that,

$0<|x-p|<\delta \implies |f(x)| \le M$

That's how I did:

Given that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}f(x) = L$, then for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that

$0<|x-p|<\delta \implies L-\epsilon <f(x)< L+\epsilon$

Now let $M=|L|+\epsilon$. We know that $L \le |L|$ and $-|L| \le L$, then

$f(x)<L+\epsilon \le |L|+\epsilon=M$ and $-M=-|L|-\epsilon \le L-\epsilon<f(x)$

Then $-M<f(x)<M$.

This way, there is $\delta>0$ and $M>0$ such that

$0<|x-p|<\delta \implies |f(x)| \le M$

Is this correct ?

Comment: It looks good to me.

Comment: I would take $\varepsilon=1.$ Morevoer the proof is slightly shorter when applying the equivalent condition $\lim_{x\to p}[(f(x)-L]=0.$